# Unexpected error occured while trying to store data

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I received an unexpected error while trying to launch my application. No information is displayed on logcat, but I am under the premises that it was due for the following reasons:
1) Trying to store the seekbar values information recorded by the user into parse to be able to retrieve it later. Storing the EditText such as name, age, headline and radiobox such as gender works fine, but its when I include the seek that the application fails to run.

Below is the activity code

....

Below is the layout code
Al though I think the issue is more with profileactivity activity code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollProfile"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/dark_texture_blue" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="797dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilePicturePreview"
        android:layout_width="132dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border_image"
        android:alpha="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bRemove"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etxtage"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etxtname"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#330099"
        android:text="Upload from Facebook"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPictureSelect"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etxtname"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profilePicturePreview"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:onClick="pickPhoto"
        android:text="Select photo from gallery"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:text="Preferred Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Profile Creation"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtname"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:hint="Please type your name here"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtname"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Upload your Profile Picture"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/texperience"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rimale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Male"
            android:textColor="#f2f2f2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rifemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female"
            android:textColor="#f2f2f2" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarDistance"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:progress="50" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rlmale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Male"
            android:textColor="#f2f2f2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rlfemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Female"
            android:textColor="#f2f2f2" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarMinimumAge"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:progress="25" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtage"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Minimum Age Looking For"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seekBarDistanceValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tMinAge"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarDistance"
        android:text="50"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="Search Distance "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tMinAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarMinimumAge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="25"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tMaxAge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Headline"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tMinAge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Maximum Age Looking For"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarMaximumAge"
        android:layout_width="221dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:progress="50" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tMaxAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarMaximumAge"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="50"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/conditions"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnConfirm"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:alpha="0.6"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/disclaimer"
        android:textColor="#99CCFF"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnConfirm"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarDistanceValue"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seekBarDistanceValue"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#151B54"
        android:text="Confirm"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="A quick description of yourself"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etxtage"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnPictureSelect"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Please type your age here"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="2"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnConfirm"
        android:text="Looking for"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texperience"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etxtheadline"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:text="I am a"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btnConfirm"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnConfirm"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="#25383C"
        android:text="Back"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bRemove"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:text="Age"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ADD8E6"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Thanks in advance for your help. Any assistance would greatly be appreciated and if you require any clarification, let me know.

Update 2

```
public class ProfileCreation extends Activity {

    private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    FrameLayout layout;
    Button save;
    protected EditText mName;
    protected EditText mAge;
    protected EditText mHeadline;
    protected ImageView mprofilePicture;
    RadioButton male, female;
    String gender;
    RadioButton lmale, lfemale;
    String lgender;
    protected SeekBar seekBarMinimum;
    protected SeekBar seekBarMaximum;
    protected SeekBar seekBarDistance;


    protected Button mConfirm;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_creation);

        RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main); 

        v.requestFocus();

        Parse.initialize(this, "ID", "ID");

        mName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtname);
        mAge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtage);
        mHeadline = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtheadline);
        mprofilePicture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
        male = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rimale);
        female = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rifemale);
        lmale = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rlmale);
        lfemale = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rlfemale);
        seekBarMinimum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarMinimumAge);
        seekBarMaximum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarMaximumAge);
        seekBarDistance = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.tvseekBarDistanceValue);




        mConfirm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnConfirm);
        mConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String name = mName.getText().toString();
                String age = mAge.getText().toString();
                String headline = mHeadline.getText().toString();




                age = age.trim();
                name = name.trim();
                headline = headline.trim();

                if (age.isEmpty() || name.isEmpty() || headline.isEmpty()) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileCreation.this);
                    builder.setMessage(R.string.signup_error_message)
                        .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
                else {
                    // create the new user!
                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

                    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

                     seekBarMaximum.getProgress();
                     seekBarMinimum.getProgress();
                     seekBarDistance.getProgress();



                    if(male.isChecked())
                        gender = "Male";
                    else
                        gender = "Female";

                    if(lmale.isChecked())
                        lgender = "Male";
                    else
                        lgender = "Female";


                    currentUser.put("Name", name); 
                    currentUser.put("Age", age); 
                    currentUser.put("Headline", headline); 
                    currentUser.put("Gender", gender);
                    currentUser.put("Looking_Gender", lgender);
                    currentUser.put("Minimum_Age", seekBarMinimum);
                    currentUser.put("Maximum_Age", seekBarMaximum);
                    currentUser.put("Maximum_Distance_Age", seekBarDistance);




                    currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                            if (e == null) {
                                // Success!
                                Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileCreation.this, MoodActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                            else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileCreation.this);
                                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                    .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                dialog.show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });



        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarDistance);
        final TextView seekBarValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvseekBarDistanceValue);

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                seekBarValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

        }); // Add this

        Button mcancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        mcancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ProfileCreation.this.startActivity(new Intent(ProfileCreation.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });




        SeekBar seekBarMinimum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarMinimumAge);
        final TextView txtMinimum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMinAge);

        seekBarMinimum.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                txtMinimum.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

        }); // Add this

        SeekBar seekBarMaximum = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sbseekBarMaximumAge);
        final TextView txtMaximum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMaxAge);

        seekBarMaximum.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                txtMaximum.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            }

        }); // Add this




        Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPictureSelect);
        buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });

    } 

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                    && null != data) {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            }

        }

        private byte[] readInFile(String path) throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            byte[] data = null;
            File file = new File(path);
            InputStream input_stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                    file));
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            data = new byte[16384]; // 16K
            int bytes_read;
            while ((bytes_read = input_stream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                buffer.write(data, 0, bytes_read);
            }
            input_stream.close();
            return buffer.toByteArray();

        }
    }
```

Logcat

```
08-13 00:11:26.924: E/AndroidRuntime(9155): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 00:11:26.924: E/AndroidRuntime(9155): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 9155
08-13 00:11:26.924: E/AndroidRuntime(9155): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dooba.beta/com.dooba.beta.ProfileCreation}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.SeekBar
08-13 00:11:26.924: E/AndroidRuntime(9155):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
```

Comment: There should be something in logcat if application crashed. Try restarting eclipse, logcat stops logging for me quite often. Also, it's debatable, but I suggest you don't use `if` statements without curly braces.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Indeed, after restarting eclipse and emulator, I was able to see logcat message. I have included the message under the update section of my initial post. I have already tried cleaning the project, but the issue persist. If you could kindly take a look it, that would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The lesson:

Once again, not following naming conventions causes error. Next time I suggest you prefix your TextView with `tv`, seekbars with `sb`, buttons with `b` and etc.

As of [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html):

> Subsequent characters may be letters, digits, dollar signs, or
>   underscore characters. Conventions (and common sense) apply to this
>   rule as well. When choosing a name for your variables, use full words
>   instead of cryptic abbreviations. Doing so will make your code easier
>   to read and understand. In many cases it will also make your code
>   self-documenting; fields named cadence, speed, and gear, for example,
>   are much more intuitive than abbreviated versions, such as s, c, and
>   g. Also keep in mind that the name you choose must not be a keyword or
>   reserved word.

And finally, the problem itself:

```
    In Activity.java:
    seekBarDistance = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarDistanceValue);
    final TextView seekBarValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seekBarDistanceValue);

    In layout.xml:
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seekBarDistanceValue"
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response and clarification. I did indeed follow your advice and adjusted the ID name as such. However, the issue persist and I have update the updated code under my initial post. If you could kindly take a look at it, that would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error the other day and for some reason changing the id of the view (in your case the seekbar) solved the issue. It could possibly be caused by some kind of name clash, although I was never able to work out where the clash was in mine.